# Xcode15 - The "backgroundImage" color asset name resolves to the symbol "background" which already exists. Try renaming the asset

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, xcode15

I build my iOS project on Xcode15 and I received a warning:

```
The "backgroundImage" color asset name resolves to the symbol "background" which already exists. 
Try renaming the asset.
```

---

My assets include two colors: 'background' and 'backgroundImage'. Xcode automatically generates the following code for:

**background**

```
/// The "background" asset catalog color resource.
static let background = ColorResource(name: "background", bundle: resourceBundle)
```

However, the **backgroundImage** color is causing the warning mentioned above.

I know Xcode 15 can automatically create Swift symbols for your resources without any third party.

I'm having trouble understanding why the 'backgroundImage' color asset name is resolving to the symbol 'background' and suggesting that I rename it to 'backgroundImage.' Can anyone explain the reason for this?

Does anyone could you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off automatic generation using build option:
"Generate Asset Symbols" set to "No"

Comment: "Generate Asset Symbols" can be found in "Build Settings" in your app's target. Set it to "No"